# Imagen dentro de un div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy realizando una pequeña página web pero tengo algunos problemas con los estilos. Mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo un slider de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora  bien, usando la clase `img-resposive` de bootstrap, las imágenes se adaptan a sus contenedores. Sin embargo necesito que, en el `col-md-4`,  que a su vez contiene 3 `article` con una imagen cada uno, la imagen se desborde del article pero no invada los otros.

Es decir, la imagen sería el recuadro amarillo, y

1. La imagen se desborde del div
2. Se centre verticalmente
3. Lo que se ha desbordado arriba y abajo se oculte para que no se invadan los demás articles.

Comment: Hola! Te recomiendo adjuntar el código que hayas logrado hasta ahora para que podamos ayudarte, Saludos!

Comment: Necesitas aplicarle al contenedor de la imagen unas clases CSS con algunos parametros. Te doy algunos consejos: con width y height (teninedo `display:block`) consigues que se llene todo el contenedor de la imagen. Por el contrario, si quieres que la imagen sea 1:1 y se oculte, el ccontenedor debe tener una propiedad en CSS que sea `overflow:hidden`. A ver si con algo de eso puedes hacer algo ;)

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con que la imagen se desborde del div?

Comment: la idea es lograr que la imagen no se "aplaste" al re dimensionar el alto de la imagen, es decir mantenga su altura original y posteriormente centrar la imagen no importa que se vuelen cabezas  o pies por así decirlo. En unos momentos anexo el código muchas gracias

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, @UnsignedFoo tu respuesta  ha solucionado mi problema muchas gracias

Comment: @UnsignedFoo por favor publica tu comentario como respuesta; así el OP aceptará su respuesta y así la pregunta no quedará "sin respuesta". Saludos.

Comment: @MissaelArmenta un placer, ahora te añado la respuesta a la pregunta. Agradeceré un puntito positivo en ella. Pasa un buen dia!

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas aplicarle al contenedor de la imagen unas clases CSS con algunos parametros. 
Te doy algunos consejos: con `width` y `height` (teninedo `display:block`) consigues que se llene todo el contenedor de la imagen. 
Por el contrario, si quieres que la imagen sea 1:1 y se oculte, el contenedor debe tener una propiedad en CSS que sea `overflow:hidden`.

A ver si con algo de eso puedes hacer algo ;)

Me alegro de haber ayudado. Pasa un buen dia!

Answer (score 1):

Podrías probar combinaciones de las propiedades `overflow-x` (para manejar el desbordamiento horizontal), y `overflow-y` (para manejar el desbordamiento vertical).  Como no proporcionas código adicional o más información de lo que quieres lograr, es un poco difícil.

Te dejo un [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MFRodriguez/qpg8xy4L/5/) para que veas las propiedades `overflow-x` y `overflow-y` en acción.

Espero te ayude.

Answer (score -1):

No sé si entiendo bien que es lo necesitas exactamente. Sería mejor que compartieras tu código para ver como lo tienes y sobre eso poder ayudarte. De todas formas, lo que entiendo es que necesitas que la imagen se coloque ocupando todo el 'article' y para eso podrías realizarlo por ejemplo así:

```
.claseImg {background: url('url de la imagen') no-repeat center center: background-size:cover}
```

Si además quieres que se coloque el título de la imagen sobre la parte superior de esta es este título el que debes mover, por ejemplo:

```
.claseTitulo {position:relative: margin-top:25px; background: #000 .3; text-align:center}
```